# How to send notifications in between phones of the same local network?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-notifications, android-networking

I am developing an application with an internal server (andro php),and I would like this application to send notifications to users that are connected to this network.

This network has not internet access, it's just a local network.

I am familiar with c2dm and xmpp, but these are only valid for when I have internet connection (in this case is a LAN without internet).

Anyone has any idea of ​​what I propose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **broadcast data over the wifi**. Essentially, this allows you to send data without knowing who will receive it. If your app (running on another phone) is expecting certain data, you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for the UDP packets. Examples can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/finnjohnsen/3654994), [here](http://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/wiki/AndroidUDP), and other places on the web.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is somewhat correct,I continued looking and the idea is to create a local server xmpp , and I have planned to do with the xmpp server, do you think this is good idea?.because my app must send different notifications according to the role to which the user has logged

Comment: @DelariJesus, This also sounds like it could work. I did not look too in depth of how the XMPP protocol works, however it is designed to send notifications, which seems like a good fit for you. It also looks like there are some open source XMPP options for Android, such as [this](https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android) or [this](http://beem-project.com).

Comment: thanks ,the two options are correct,I will look which is more effective